# How do I get human names from ransack attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I am using ransack to build a search form:

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :title_or_description_or_request_number_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :title_or_description_or_request_number_cont %>

  <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-info' %>
<% end %>
```

My model is called WorkRequest

The label for this displays the following text:

**Title or Description or Request number contains**

I want to use this text in output on the page when nothing is found - something like:

**Unable to find a work request where Title or Description or Request number contains ...**

I was hoping to use the human_attribute_name method to retrieve the text, but both of these:

```
WorkRequest.human_attribute_name :title_or_description_or_request_number_cont

WorkRequest.new.human_attribute_name :title_or_description_or_request_number_cont
```

Output: **Title or description or request number cont**

(ends 'cont' instead of 'contains')

How is label constructing its text output if it is not using human_attribute_name, and how can I construct the same text?

I know I can do a simple substitute of 'cont' for 'contains', but I want a  solution that will modify the text output to match any ransack style search query (e.g. ones ending _eq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a solution:

```
context = Ransack::Context.for_class WorkRequest
text =    Ransack::Translate.attribute(
           :title_or_description_or_request_number_cont, 
           context: context
          )
```

That outputs:

**Title or Description or Request number contains**

Comment: Very helpful, especially the context part that was not explained anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: @AndreiHorak I was a little confused too as to how to build a context for the attribute method. Then I thought to myself, how would I want to build a context: I'd like to use a Context class, so I looked for that and there it was.